# How to enable client side evaluation In EF core 3.0?

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I know that is wrong to enable client side evaluation but i want to enable it anyway.
I am wondering how to do it in ef core 3.0?

Comment: You can't. It's gone. [Unsupported client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#unsupported-client-evaluation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly switch to client-side evaluation in your queries using AsEnumerable.

```cs
var specialCustomers =
  context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(n))
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to LINQ to Objects to client-eval the rest of the query
    .Where(c => IsSpecialCustomer(c));
```

Comment: It looks like there is no other way. at least is good that is not allowed any longer.